# how can i enable filesystemwatcher to fire each and every file created event without loosing any

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I want to collect the path of the files as soon as any file is created in a particular folder.

I used a `List<string>` and the `FileSystemWatcher` component. I add the paths to the `List` in the `Created` event, and everything works fine.

However, when there are many small files created, say around 2000, the `Created` event is fired only 1200 times. When I don't add the path to the list in the `Created` event, though, it is called for 2000 times. I tried using a separate thread, but to no avail.

How can I enable `FileSystemWatcher` to fire each and every event without missing some of the events?

Comment: Can you show your implementation?

Comment: sorry man.no code. I am on mobile.

the created event has only one line code i.e. Listinstance.add(eventargs.path);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to implement the Error event so you *know* when things go wrong.  Keep the notification event handlers short and snappy, just add the file to a list and get out.  Process the list in another worker thread.  Increasing InternalBufferSize can help but should be avoided.

Comment: i am just adding the path to the list but still it is not firing all event.i used a seprate thread but no fruit..it may be that while i am adding path to list,some events may have been avoided.is it so!

Comment: Are you using a lock?  Required, these events run on another thread.

Comment: i am not using any kind of lock.the event contains just 1 line of code i.e. List.add...

Comment: increasing InternalBufferSize solved the problem.thankyou sir

Answer (score 4):

chances are it's a race condition and 2 files are added to the list at the same time. last write wins. locking the list before adding to the list would prevent this. If you are using .net 4.0 you could also use a concurrent dictionary or readwriteslim to assist with the concurrency issues.

Comment: Yep I just reread the question now that's edited this makes sense. Sounds like the Component is getting all the events but he's loosing the data when he handles the events

Answer (score 1):

I have found, IIRC, that the `FileSystemWatcher` will not 'see' any new files while it is processing a given `Created` event. That is, while the `Created` event handler is processing, any new files created do not raise the event.

Have you tried making the processing faster (kick off an async thread, perhaps)? I know you mentioned a separate thread, but without code, it's hard to tell what that thread is doing or how it is used.